# Laravel app is not displaying images on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, symlink

`Laravel` app is not displaying images on server. It is giving `symlink()` cannot create error. because of this my slider images are not displaying.

I've tried to run several commands on server like:

```
cd /path/to/public_html/public/
ln -s ../storage/app/public/ ./storage
```

But it doesn't work. I want to remove error and show images.

Comment: Can you please specify your problem, like you can provide a screenshot, list of error you're getting, which server are you using and with which configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a special command made to create a simlink from your storage to the public folder:

`php artisan storage:link`